# How to get transactions from a wallet address?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, pending-transactions

Is there a way to get all the transactions from a wallet address using `ethers.js` or `viem.sh`?

Or are there any third-party libraries that have this functionality?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```typescript
const transactions = await sdk.getTransactions(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really natively, it'd be easiest to use a third-party API for this. You can use Etherscan if you'd like, https://etherscan.io/apis

Or something a bit more dev-focused like Covalent, https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/transactions/get-paginated-transactions-for-address-v3/

*If you prefer an SDK format, Chainstack offers an SDK for Covalent: https://chainstack.com/marketplace/covalent/ & https://github.com/chainstacklabs/chainstack-covalent-sdk/*